# install4j launcher issue on Mac OSX app store application

Tags: install4j

We’re using install4j to create installers for our Java application, PDF Studio.

We’re currently trying to submit our application to the Apple store and for this, need a pkg file. We’ve created a pkg file from the Application folder that is created after running the dmg installer created by install4j and are working on removing one by one all the warnings and errors reported by the Apple store.

One issue we are having is that symlinks are not allowed by the Apple store and the JRE contains a symlink for a file called libjli.dylib.

When we try to remove the symlink or replace it with the actual file, the i4j launcher for our application is broken.

When we remove the file from the install folder:

rm /Applications/PDF\ Studio\ 2018.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre.bundle/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib

We get an error message on launch saying "Java SE 8" couldn't be loaded because it's executable couldn't be located."

If we try to copy the file to the symlink location:

cp /Applications/PDF\ Studio\ 2018.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib /Applications/PDF\ Studio\ 2018.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre.bundle/Contents/MacOS

Then the launcher fails with no error message dialog.

If we run with install4j log enabled:

INSTALL4J_LOG=yes /Applications/PDF\ Studio\ 2018.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub

Then it will print "Error: could not find libjava.dylib."

Has anyone tried to do this and made it work?

It seems like the launcher is looking under /MacOS/libjli.dylib. We think it is the JavaApplicationStub executable file that decides where to look which is created by install4j.

Is there is a way to set where the launcher looks for the jre.bundle executable libjli.dylib?

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the DMG and edit the Info.plist file so that it contains

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>../Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib</string>
```

We will check if we can do this in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That resolved the issue with launching. However it did not pass the Apple Store verification. When uploading the build, I get a new error saying "Bad CFBudleExecutable. Cannot find executable file that matches the value of CFBundleExecutable in the nested bundle Java SE 8"... Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have any experience with publishing to the Apple Store, so I cannot say. We may try to support this in a future version.

Comment: For me it was `<string>../Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib</string>` so for anyone reading this in the future make sure to check the actual path where `libjli.dylib` is.